# running of curl in terminal in mac os give incompatible library version error

Tags: macos, curl

While running curl command in mac terminal gives following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.58.0/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 9.0.0
```

I tried to add path to bash_profile Its not working . how to make curl work in mac os?

Comment: Unless you need a specific version `MacOS` is bundled with `curl` . Perhaps try `brew uninstall curl` and see if the stock one works.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the recommendation from Kamil.S comment and I did those steps to solve the situation:

```
brew uninstall --force --ignore-dependencies curl
brew install curl
```

Also had to reinstall things depending on curl afterward (whatever was previously listed as dependent from `brew uninstall --force curl`):

```
brew uninstall --force git
brew install git
```